# lambda as argument to jinja2 filter?

Tags: python, lambda, jinja2

I'd like to have a custom filter in jinja2 like this:

```
{{ my_list|my_real_map_filter(lambda i: i.something.else)|some_other_filter }}
```

But when I implement it, I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'i'
```

It appears jinja2's syntax does not allow for lambdas as arguments? Is there some nice workaround? For now, I'm creating the lambda in python then passing it to the template as a variable, but I'd rather be able to just create it in the template.

Comment: Please, never use complex logic in templates. They are not designed for this. You should consider as lightweight templates as possible with most logical operations on the backend. Imagine what would you say after finding something similar after another developer? Consider [buildin filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters). The `lambda` creates an anonymous function that is much harder to debug.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to do what I want using the built in filters? (i.e. I have a list of objects and I need to access an attribute of a child of each of the objects?) I don't think what I'm trying to do is really any more complicated in a logical sense than what the built in "map" allows, but I don't think I can do what I want with the built in map. Please show me if I can!

Comment: The question is `lambda as argument to jinja2 filter?` and the answer is `No, you cannot pass general Python expression to filter in Jinja2 template`. Seems to be correct. Now, if you want to use a custom filter on a list of objects in template, the question is 'why'. Why not filter objects *before* passing the list to template? Why do you need to filter *after* passing it to the template?

Comment: Because my filter is doing templatey stuff, I think it should be in the template rather than the controller. My main object Suggestion has an attribute contacts which is a list of Contact objects and each Contact has the attributes name and url. I want to construct a comma separated (with an 'and' if appropriate) representation of the linked names.

Comment: Well, I tried to use `lambda` in Jinja2 templates and it seems it does not work as you expect. I would still suggest to use all logic in controller. You should to pass to the template only the data that should be shown there - just construct a `dict` and use it with `join()`. This is not a single-page app and any changes in the view will be after you refresh the page. And consider someone reading your code and trying to understand why you did so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot pass general Python expression to filter in Jinja2 template

The confusion comes from jinja2 templates being similar to Python syntax in many aspects, but you shall take it as code with completely independent syntax.

Jinja2 has strict rules, what can be expected at which part of the template and it generally does not allow python code as is, it expect exact types of expressions, which are quite limited.

This is in line with the concept, that presentation and model shall be separated, so template shall not allow too much logic. Anyway, comparing to many other templating options, Jinja2 is quite permissible and allows quite a lot of logic in templates.

Answer (score 8):

I have a workaround, I'm sorting a dict object:

```
registers = dict(
    CMD = dict(
        address = 0x00020,
        name = 'command register'),
    SR = dict(
        address = 0x00010,
        name = 'status register'),
)
```

I wanted to loop over the register dict, but sort by address.  So I needed a way to sort by the 'address' field.  To do this, I created a custom filter and pass the lambda expression as a string, then I use Python's builtin eval() to create the real lambda:

```
def my_dictsort(value, by='key', reverse = False):

    if by == 'key':
        sort_by = lambda x: x[0].lower() # assumes key is a str

    elif by == 'value':
        sort_by = lambda x: x[1]

    else:
        sort_by = eval(by)   # assumes lambda string, you should error check

    return sorted(value, key = sort_by, reverse = reverse)
```

With this function, you can inject it into the jinja2 environment like so:

```
env = jinja2.Environment(...)
env.filters['my_dictsort'] = my_dictsort
env.globals['lookup'] = lookup            # queries a database, returns dict
```

And then call it from your template:

```
{% for key, value in lookup('registers') | my_dict_sort("lambda x:x[1]['address']") %}
{{"""\
    static const unsigned int ADDR_{key} = 0x0{address:04X}; // {name}
""" | format(key = key, address = value['address'], name = value['name']) 
}}
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
static const unsigned int ADDR_SR = 0x00010; // status register
static const unsigned int ADDR_CMD = 0x00020; // command register
```

So you can pass a lambda as a string, but you'll have to add a custom filter to do it.

Comment: Nice solution, but one aspect that might be worth considering is the readability of the template. If a template's output can be easily discerned from just reading the filters and commands therein, that is a good heuristic for effective design.

Answer (score 1):

i've had to handle the same issue recently, I've had to create a `list` of `dict` in my `Ansible` template, and this is not included in the base filters.

Here's my workaroud :

```py
def generate_list_from_list(list, target, var_name="item"):
    """
    :param list: the input data
    :param target: the applied transformation on each item of the list
    :param var_name: the name of the parameter in the lambda, to be able to change it if needed
    :return: A list containing for each item the target format
    """

    # I didn't put the error handling to keep it short
    # Here I evaluate the lambda template, inserting the name of the parameter and the output format
    f = eval("lambda {}: {}".format(var_name, target)) 

    return [f(item) for item in list]

# ---- Ansible filters ----
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'generate_list_from_list': generate_list_from_list
        }
```

I'm then able to use it this way :

(`my_input_list` is a `list`of `string`, but it would work with a `list` of anything)

```
# I have to put quotes between the <target> parameter because it evaluates as a string
# The variable is not available at the time of the templating so it would fail otherwise
my_variable: "{{ my_input_list | generate_list_from_list(\"{ 'host': item, 'port': 8000 }\") }}"
```

Or if I want to rename the lambda parameter :

```
my_variable: "{{ my_input_list | generate_list_from_list(\"{ 'host': variable, 'port': 8000 }\", var_name="variable") }}"
```

This outputs :

- when called directly in `Python`:

```py
[{'host': 'item1', 'port': 8000}, {'host': 'item2', 'port': 8000}]
```

- when called in a template (a yaml file in my example, but as it returns a list you can do whatever you want once the list is transformed) :

```
my_variable:
-    host: item1
     port: 8000
-    host: item2
     port: 8000
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Where do you put the Python code?